# Properties of the cofinite topology on an uncountable set

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be an uncountable set and let $\mathcal T = \{U \subseteq X : U = \varnothing\text{ or }U^c \text{ is finite} \}$.
>
> Then is topological space $(X,\mathcal T)$
>
> 1. separable?
> 2. Hausdorff?
> 3. second-countable (has a countable basis)?
> 4. first-countable (has a countable basis at each point)?

I am confirmed about (2), $(X,\mathcal T)$ is not a Hausdorff space because we have a result $(X,\mathcal T)$ is Hausdorff iff $D = \{(x,x) : x \in X \}$ is closed , but $D$ is closed if $D^c$ is open and $D^c$ is open if $D^c$ is finite or $\varnothing$ which is not possible . so $(X,\mathcal T)$ is not a Hausdorff.

Please tell me about other three option. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

**Hints:**

1. Show that *every* infinite set is dense; in particular, the countably infinite sets.  (Fix an infinite $A \subseteq X$, and show that $U \cap A \neq \varnothing$ for every nonempty open $U \subseteq X$.)
2. Show that any two nonempty open sets have nonempty intersection.
3. If $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ is countable, then the set $A = \bigcup_{U \in \mathcal{B}} ( X \setminus U )$ is countable (since it is a countable union of finite sets). Pick $x \in X \setminus A$, and consider $V = X \setminus \{ x \}$.  (Is it a union of sets in $\mathcal{B}$?)
4. *Very* similar to the above.

---

For your attempt at the non-Hausdorffness, you need to be a <s>little bit</s> lot more careful.  You need to show that $D$ is not closed in the square $X \times X$. In order to proceed as you have done, you would first have to show that the product $X \times X$ also has the co-fintie topology (since you make an appeal to this).  However this is not true.  If $A, B \subseteq X$ are finite nonempty, then $( X \setminus A ) \times ( X \setminus B )$ is open in $X \times X$, but it is not co-finite (since for any $a \in A$ the uncountable set $\{ \langle a , x \rangle : x \in X \}$ is disjoint from this set).

Comment: Perhaps worth pointing out:  one could do 4. first, and in the same stroke take care of 3.

Comment: @Arthur Fisher : I understood your all the three proofs and I am trying the fourth. Thank you very much